# Filtering list column with value in other column

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

I am trying to filter a nested dataframe/list column with the value contained in another column of the main (?) dataframe. Unfortunately, my code below doesn't work, and I think the problem is that the way I am referring to `search_term` inside the `map_if` is not correct. I suspect that it takes the entire vector/column and not only the single value for each row of `search_term`. I use map_if to check if the nested nested dataframe, which i want to filter, is not empty (checking is number of rows in `nested_data_nrow`). Grateful for any hint. Many thanks. Below my reprex.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'dplyr' was built under R version 4.1.3
df_nest <- structure(list(nested_data = list(structure(list(places_bank_name = c(
  "ZiraatBank",
  "UniCredit Bank", "Sparkasse Bank", "Intesa Sanpaolo Banka",
  "Raiffeisen BANK", "EKI"
)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
)), structure(list(places_bank_name = c(
  "Raiffeisen BANK (iPoslovnica)",
  "KIB Banka", "Raiffeisen BANK - Agencija Bužim", "BBI Bosna Bank International"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(places_bank_name = "Casopis Financing"), row.names = c(
  NA,
  -1L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")), structure(list(
  places_bank_name = "UniCredit Bank"
), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))), nested_data_nrow = c(
  6,
  4, 1, 1
), search_term = c(
  "BBI|Bosna Banka", "Komercijalno-investiciona|KIB",
  "Raiffeisen", "UniCredit"
), bank_name = c(
  "Bosna Banka International",
  "Komercijalno-investiciona banka d.d. V.Kladusa", "Raiffeisen Bank d.d. BiH",
  "UniCredit d.d. Mostar"
)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c(
  "tbl_df",
  "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df_nest
#> # A tibble: 4 x 4
#>   nested_data      nested_data_nrow search_term                   bank_name     
#>   <list>                      <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>         
#> 1 <tibble [6 x 1]>                6 BBI|Bosna Banka               Bosna Banka I~
#> 2 <tibble [4 x 1]>                4 Komercijalno-investiciona|KIB Komercijalno-~
#> 3 <tibble [1 x 1]>                1 Raiffeisen                    Raiffeisen Ba~
#> 4 <tibble [1 x 1]>                1 UniCredit                     UniCredit d.d~

df_nest_filtered <- df_nest %>%
  mutate(nest_data_filtered = map_if(
    nested_data,
    nested_data_nrow > 0,
    ~ .x %>%
      filter(str_detect(
        places_bank_name,
        regex(search_term, ignore_case = T)
      ))
  )) %>%
  mutate(nest_data_filtered_nrow = map_dbl(nest_data_filtered, nrow)) %>%
  select(bank_name, search_term, everything())
#> Warning in stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, negate = negate, opts_regex =
#> opts(pattern)): longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `nest_data_filtered = map_if(...)`.
#> Caused by error in `filter()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `..1 = str_detect(places_bank_name,
#>   regex(search_term, ignore_case = T))`.
#> x Input `..1` must be of size 1, not size 4.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple columns going inside `map_if` and this creates a length issue as each element of `nested_data` should be matched with the corresponding 'search_term'. Therefore, `pmap` would be better

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
df_nest2 <- df_nest %>%
   mutate(nest_data_filtered = pmap(across(
     c(nested_data, nested_data_nrow, search_term)), 
    ~ if(..2 > 0) ..1 %>%
     filter(str_detect(places_bank_name, 
      regex(..3, ignore_case = TRUE)) ) else ..1))
```

-output

```
> df_nest2$search_term
[1] "BBI|Bosna Banka"     
[2] "Komercijalno-investiciona|KIB"
[3] "Raiffeisen"         
[4] "UniCredit"                    
> df_nest2$nest_data_filtered
[[1]]
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# … with 1 variable: places_bank_name <chr>

[[2]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  places_bank_name
  <chr>           
1 KIB Banka       

[[3]]
# A tibble: 0 × 1
# … with 1 variable: places_bank_name <chr>

[[4]]
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  places_bank_name
  <chr>           
1 UniCredit Bank
```

---

Or another option is with `map2` and `case_when`

```
df_nest %>%
   mutate(nest_data_filtered = case_when(nested_data_nrow > 0 
     ~ map2(nested_data, search_term,
    ~ .x %>% filter(str_detect(places_bank_name,
     regex(.y, ignore_case = TRUE)))), TRUE ~ nested_data))
```

Comment: Excellent, many thank, @akrun! 2 things, if you don't mind: 
1) Version 1 - why do you use across and close the bracket immediately after selecting the columns/before specifying the fn. I thought pmap requires a list?
2) Version 2 - Oddly, the second version (case_when) doesn't work when I apply it to my full data. Error: ! object 'places_res_raw_nrow' not found; Any idea why that could be?

Comment: @zoowalk In the first case, `across` is used for just selecting the columns.  You may use `select` as well, but this is more compact, 2) I was doubtful about the case_when approach because it checks the type etc and if there is an issue, it could break